# Lua - Is there a concept of io.lines when you have a list of items in your string?

Tags: lua

Is there a route like io.lines that you can use against a string (that is a list of something) ?   For example i have a list of urls, I’d like to circle through ?

Just curious if i can only do this sort of thing when its a separate file..

```
local iconurls = [[

https://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_left_button.png
https://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_right_button.png
https://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_up_button.png
https://findicons.com/files/icons/2332/super_mono/64/navigation_down_button.png

]]

for line in io.lines(iconurls) do
    print(“url = “ ..line)
end
```

Comment: `for line in iconurls:gmatch"[^\n]+" do`

Comment: Might want to make that a `[^\r\n]+` to account for just CR and CRLF.